# View docker file for AWS deep learning container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

I am setting up a sagemaker endpoint and using `pytorch-inference:1.13.1-gpu-py39` as my base docker image:

```
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:1.13.1-gpu-py39
```

Is there some way I can see the actual source docker file for that image? AWS has a long list of them here: https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md - is it possible to check each of them out?

Answer (score 0):

You can go [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/deep-learning-containers/latest/devguide/dlc-release-notes.html) and click on the desired image for the release notes of containers, you find for example the list of installed packages. You can then follow the link under "For details about this release, check out our GitHub release-notes.". If you download the source you find your dockerfile in `pytorch\inference\docker\1.13\py3`.